# How to simplify an expectation divided by an expecation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let:

- $p(\mathbf{x}, t | \mathbf{x}_0)$ be a time-varying conditional probability density function;
- $q(\mathbf{x}_0)$ be a time-invariant marginal probability density function;
- $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x} | \mathbf{x}_0)$ be a time-invariant conditional vector-valued function;
- $$\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}, t) = \frac{\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}_0 \sim q}\left[ \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x} | \mathbf{x}_0) p(\mathbf{x}, t | \mathbf{x}_0) \right]}{\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}_0 \sim q}\left[p(\mathbf{x}, t | \mathbf{x}_0) \right]}.$$

Does $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}, t)$ really depend on time $t$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $f(x,t)$ definitely depends on $t$ through the dependence of $f(x|x_0)$ on $x_0$.  (See below.)

Here's one possible "simplification", though I'm not sure if it really simplifies anything.  It might help with interpretation, though.

If you write $p(x,t,x_0)=p(x,t|x_0)q(x_0)$ for the joint density, then you can write:
$$f(x,t) = \int f(x|x_0) \frac{p(x,t,x_0)}{\int p(x,t,x_0) dx_0} dx_0$$
and this fraction is the time-varying conditional density in the opposite direction $p(x_0,t|x)$, i.e., the density of the starting point $x_0$ conditioned on $x_t$ at time $t$.

In other words if these distributions describe a stochastic process $X$, then:
$$f(x,t) = \mathbb{E}_q[f(X_t|X_0)\mid X_t]$$

(In general, this will depend on $t$ because the conditional distribution of $X_0$ given $X_t$ depends on $t$.)